# "The text content of element script was not in the required format: Expected space, tab, newline, or slash but found { instead."

Tags: javascript, html, w3c-validation

My HTML is almost HTML5-compliant according to the W3C Validator, only one error is remaining: the Javascript code to configure the Google Plus buttons.

Whether I add CDATA or not, the error *"The text content of element `script` was not in the required format: Expected space, tab, newline, or slash but found `{` instead."* is displayed for this line:

```html
<script src="http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js" type="text/javascript">
   {"lang":"en","parsetags":"explicit"}
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like your trying to pass an undefined object.

Answer (score 3):

The error message is correct. A `script` tag that has its `src` attribute set [can only contain documentation](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/scripting-1.html#inline-documentation-for-external-scripts): whitespace and comments (`/* ... */` or `//...`).

If you just want to avoid the error, you could try creating the `script` tag with js, as in the [asynchronous load example](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/#example-async-load). This doesn't make it valid but at least the initially served html will be without errors and validators won't complain.

Answer (score 2):

...I sorely doubt you're going to win the validation-war, here.

If you've got a client/boss that is obsessed over validating (rather than being solid code -- because you can totally have flimsy, flaky, valid code), then you can tell them to drop g+, completely.

But Google is using that script tag to load its file, that file is finding the last script tag that loaded, and then using the inner-text for configuration of the program.

Is it completely valid syntax?
Not really, no.

Perhaps they might consider trying to work within JS-comments, but really, Google will change this stuff frequently, as they take over the world and evolve web-programming (angular.js is craaazy).

While they aren't perfect, I'd suspect that their code is more solid than just "W3C validator-approved" code.