# W3C validator error with Chatango embedded code

Tags: javascript, html, embed, w3c-validation

So I embedded a chatango tab on my website, but I get this error when validating it for HTML.

**The text content of element script was not in the required format: Expected space, tab, newline, or slash but found { instead.**

Any workarounds for this? Thank you!

```
<script id="cid0020000101807397328" data-cfasync="false" async src="//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js" style="width: 603px;height: 471px;">
{"handle":"********","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"000000","b":100,"c":"a0a0a0","d":"FFFFFF","e":"202020","g":"bbbbbb","h":"202020","j":"c0c0c0","k":"0084ef","l":"606060","m":"0084ef","n":"FFFFFF","p":"10","q":"000000","r":100,"pos":"br","cv":1,"cvfntsz":"14px","cvbg":"3366ff","cvw":600,"cvh":30,"surl":0,"allowpm":0,"cnrs":"0.35","ticker":1,"fwtickm":1}}</script>
```

Comment: As it's an undefined object it's technically not valid. There's not really a workaround but unless you're obsessed with validation then it's not actually a problem at all. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408687/the-text-content-of-element-script-was-not-in-the-required-format-expected-spac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Ben said - you cannot use code inside tag with src.

But here is some valid and working solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

    <title>chatango</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var chatango = document.createElement('script');
        chatango.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
        chatango.setAttribute('id','cid0020000101807397328');
        chatango.setAttribute('data-cfasync','false');
        chatango.setAttribute('async',true);
        chatango.setAttribute('src','//st.chatango.com/js/gz/emb.js');
        chatango.setAttribute('style','width: 603px;height: 471px;');
        chatango.innerHTML = '{"handle":"1shotgg","arch":"js","styles":{"a":"000000","b":100,"c":"a0a0a0","d":"FFFFFF","e":"202020","g":"bbbbbb","h":"202020","j":"c0c0c0","k":"0084ef","l":"606060","m":"0084ef","n":"FFFFFF","p":"10","q":"000000","r":100,"pos":"br","cv":1,"cvfntsz":"14px","cvbg":"3366ff","cvw":600,"cvh":30,"surl":0,"allowpm":0,"cnrs":"0.35","ticker":1,"fwtickm":1}}';
        document.body.appendChild(chatango);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```