# W3C HTML validation error: "The text content of element script was not in the required format"

Tags: javascript, html, w3c-validation, skel

I am using [Skel.js](https://github.com/ajlkn/skel) framework for my project.
I have an HTML validation error which is not allowing my project to pass the W3C HTML and CSS validation.

The error:

> The text content of element `script` was not in the required format: Expected space, tab, newline, or slash but found `{` instead.

Code:

```html
<script src="js/skel.min.js">
    {
        prefix: 'css/style',
        preloadStyleSheets: true,
        resetCSS: true,
        boxModel: 'border',
        grid: { gutters: 30 },
        breakpoints: {
            wide: { range: '1200-', containers: 1140, grid: { gutters: 50 } },
            narrow: { range: '481-1199', containers: 960 },
            mobile: { range: '-480', containers: 'fluid', lockViewport: true, grid: { collapse: true } }
        }
    }
</script>
```

I found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14408687/the-text-content-of-element-script-was-not-in-the-required-format-expected-spac) but I'm not sure how it applies in the context of my site.

Comment: The validator says your code is invalid. The code is invalid. Did you have a question?

Comment: @Kaiido — https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics-scripting.html#script-documentation

Comment: @Quentin ah thanks. So at fourth glance it is invalid ;-)